# How can I re-use a configuration (local module) with my Terraform project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm quite new to Terraform, so I guess I consider Terraform **modules** as "functions" that I can re-use but that's wrong. I had a scenario where I had to deploy a static web site to `cloudfront` and `s3 bucket`. At first, I configured this as raw files in my project: https://github.com/tal-rofe/tf-old/tree/main/terraform/core - you can see I have `s3.tf` and `cloudfront.tf` files, raw in my project.

But then I had to deploy an another static web application. So, because now I need 2 applications to be deployed, I could duplicate my code and create `x-cloudfront.tf`, `x-s3.tf` and `y-cloudfront.tf`, `y-s3.tf` files with same exact configuration, just differ with the domains I guess. So instead of doing so, I tried to create a module which creates `s3` and `cloudfront` resources, and then in my project, I could re-use this module to create 2 web applications.

So I have this project:
https://github.com/tal-rofe/tf-new

And here I created a module:
https://github.com/tal-rofe/tf-new/tree/main/terraform/modules/static-app

As you can see I have `variables.tf` file:

```
variable "domain_name" {
  description = "The domain name of the application"
  type        = string
}

variable "zone_id" {
  description = "The zone identifier to set domain of the application in"
  type        = string
}

variable "acm_certificate_arn" {
  description = "The certificate ARN"
  type        = string
}

variable "s3_bucket_name" {
  description = "The bucket name of the S3 bucket for the application"
  type        = string
}

variable "common_tags" {
  description = "The tags for all created resources"
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
}

variable "cloudfront_tags" {
  description = "The tags for Cloudfront resource"
  type        = map(string)
}

variable "www_redirect_bucket_tags" {
  description = "The tags for a bucket to redirect www to non-www"
  type        = map(string)
}

variable "s3_bucket_tags" {
  description = "The tags for a bucket to redirect www to non-www"
  type        = map(string)
}
```

and `output.tf` file:

```
output "cloudfront_distribution_id" {
  description = "The distribution ID of deployed Cloudfront"
  value       = module.cdn.cloudfront_distribution_id
}
```

And all other files within this module are dedicated for setting up the relevant resources, **using another public modules released**. So If I do so, I could, in my project, to use this module **twice**, provide different inputs in each declaration, and get the `cloudfront_distribution_id` output from each.

This is why I have these 2 files, using this module:
https://github.com/tal-rofe/tf-new/blob/main/terraform/core/docs-static.tf
and
https://github.com/tal-rofe/tf-new/blob/main/terraform/core/frontend-static.tf

And then, I want to output from my project the 2 created cloudfront distributions IDs:

```
output "frontend_cloudfront_distribution_id" {
  description = "The distribution ID of deployed Cloudfront frontend"
  value       = module.frontend-static.cloudfront_distribution_id
}

output "docs_cloudfront_distribution_id" {
  description = "The distribution ID of deployed Cloudfront docs"
  value       = module.docs-static.cloudfront_distribution_id
}
```

So when I start applying this whole project with terraform, I don't get these 2 outputs, but I only get one output, called `cloudfront_distribution_id`. So it seems like I get the output of the custom module I created. But I want to get the outputs of my main project.

So I don't understand what did I do wrong in providing this custom module?

I apply my configuration using GitHub action with these steps:

```yaml
            - name: Terraform setup
              uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
              with:
                terraform_wrapper: false

            - name: Terraform core init
              env:
                  TERRAFORM_BACKEND_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.TERRAFORM_BACKEND_S3_BUCKET }}
                  TERRAFORM_BACKEND_DYNAMODB_TABLE: ${{ secrets.TERRAFORM_BACKEND_DYNAMODB_TABLE }}
              run: |
                terraform -chdir="./terraform/core" init \
                -backend-config="bucket=$TERRAFORM_BACKEND_S3_BUCKET" \
                -backend-config="dynamodb_table=$TERRAFORM_BACKEND_DYNAMODB_TABLE" \
                -backend-config="region=$AWS_REGION"
                
            - name: Terraform core plan
              run: terraform -chdir="./terraform/core" plan -no-color -out state.tfplan

            - name: Terraform core apply
              run: terraform -chdir="./terraform/core" apply state.tfplan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running `terraform apply` from the `terraform/modules/static-app` folder of your project. You need to be running it from the `terraform/core` folder.

You should always run `terraform apply` from within the core/root/base folder of your Terraform code.

Comment: I run my `terraform apply` from the `terraform/core` folder. I also attached my running script, using GitHub actions, in the question.

Comment: What you describe, seeing the `cloudfront_distribution_id` output from `terraform apply` and not seeing the outputs from the core Terraform code is only possible if you are running `terraform apply` from the wrong folder. Either that, or the code you think you are running isn't actually the code you are running. Perhaps your GitHub action is running a different version of the code than you think it is. I would try using the `working-directory` setting in GitHub actions, instead of using `-chdir` on the terraform command.

Comment: Note: You should be running `terraform plan` locally to see what exactly is going to happen before attempting to do anything in GitHub Actions. That will be much easier to debug the issue than trying to debug GitHub Actions runs.

Comment: Well, I can tell that I had a previous configuration where I did have `cloudfront_distribution_id` as an output, right here: https://github.com/tal-rofe/tf-old. Then I tried using the module I described here, and got this: https://github.com/tal-rofe/tf-new. Then I applied the last, and I still got `cloudfront_distribution_id` as an output. So if that's not the custom module output I created, what could it be? Because I can ensure I run the action with my latest code base version

Comment: Well, after running local plan, I do get other output from GH plan. My local plan shows it's going to create the outputs I want, but GH won't. How could it be possible? I'm 100% sure I'm running the action on the latest commit on my main branch

Comment: How stupid. I was missing the `checkout` step (aka `git clone`) . O_O